# Generating variable frequency PWM with Attiny85

Tags: pwm, embedded, attiny85

Bit of Background: I am currently working with my ATX Power Supply and trying to re-purpose it to use its voltage outputs (3.3V, 5V and 12V). But I would like to have a PWM feature with my power supply when I complete it. For this purpose I am thinking to use Attiny85 and use it's fast PWM mode to generate what I need. I need a PWM signal whose duty cycle and frequency can be varied through the use of potentionmeter.

Problem:[Link to datasheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aTDUs-45I2Hg6mtBuHm6t9whVEOwsT-5/view?usp=sharing) Going through the datasheet, I figured out that it is possible to vary the duty cycle as I want through the manipulation of Output Compare Register (OCR). But I can only vary frequency in pre-determined values. Varying the clock prescale factor does the basic job. But what I want is PWM with frequency I can adjust with a potentiometer as I want (within the supported range of course).

Possible way for solution from my study: I came to the CTC mode in which I can vary the frequency by changing the values in OCR. But this would limit the duty cycle varying feature. So, I wonder if there is any way to combine these two modes.I came to [this thread](https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/2407451#comment-2407451) where the question deals with varying frequency only but not the duty cycle.

I can do the  basic operation of generating the PWM with fixed frequency. Although, I went through the registers involved in generating PWM, I can't scrap any idea to generate the PWM I wish for.

This is basically what my primary problem is. I would love some recommendations from this community about what I could add to the features of my power supply. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I am following you, you want to use one pot to change both the frequency and duty cycle?  Have you considered doing the PWM yourself with an IO instead of using the built-in PWM?  It seems you could read the pot with an ADC, then use that value to set the freq. and duty cycle in your PWM code using any algorithm you like (limited by the resolution of the ADC and clock prescaler).

Comment: Sorry for not adding the details. I want different pots for duty cycle and PWM. And bit-banging was the idea that came in my mind, but since I am learning the use of timer and counter, I wanted to use my newly learn skill. If there is no any way I can do that with inbuilt PWM I would certainly go with bit-banging.

Comment: How much resolution are you looking for on the frequency?  The prescaler only has so many values.

Comment: My calculation showed the maximum is 4KHz and minimum is 4Hz with 1MHz clock. In order to go further I have to adjust the fuse bits everytime I crank the pot.

Comment: I would try using an interrupt every timer overflow to change the values of ICR, OCRA and OCRB to reflect the new values you read via ADC on the two pots.

Comment: I just noticed you said ATTINY85...which doesn't have a 16bit timer.  Are you stuck with that chip?

Comment: Yeah, I bought a 328P and attiny85 few days back but I destroyed my 328P due to overvoltage. And I can't go to the market to buy new one because it's still horrible situation here doe to pandemic. And the next factor is I don't wanna use 328P which has lot more to offer than attiny85 for my small project.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that.  Without the extra functions available to the 16bit timer, I'm not sure I know how to accomplish what you are looking for.  Hopefully somebody can chime in with a cool trick and we can both learn something.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. Let's see if anyone else has something we can learn from.

Comment: @Giga-Byte It is a lot of work just laying out a crafted design for a system where you have two pots; one to control frequency and the other to control duty cycle. Personally, I'd want precision control with the ability to exactly reach the minimum and maximum of both, with zero slop or error when reaching the "stops", and that I could calibrate positions on the dial where they would not drift over time, temperature, dust, etc. This likely means rotary A/B quadrature (optical, my choice) dials and knobs with visual displays and a selection of output types. But then I'd have a nice instrument.

Comment: @Giga-Byte Bit-banging will be a problem unless you are really good in assembly code and studying instruction execution time and the time along different branch edges. More, you may need to select a processor that actually has precision timing for instructions. (Not sure about your selection, but it's something I'd look at closely.) Even then, the whole thing is quite tricky to work out if you want to avoid variability in the output. (If set for 50%, you may not want to see it jitter all over the place between 47% and 54%, for example, because your looping and branching is not well crafted.)

Comment: Would you recommend me giving up this chip @jonk?

Comment: @Giga-Byte No, don't give up on it. You mentioned above you are stuck with it. (There are much better chips with much better timer mechanisms in them [the B7 timer system in the MSP430, for example.] But that doesn't mean you have to use them -- especially when you can't.) I'm just suggesting that you need some "sit-down" time while you work through the details. If you don't have good peripherals and you are forced to bit-bang as a result, then sit down and examine the "worst case" situation and see if it is achievable. If you use C for this, I don't think the results will be good. That's all.

Comment: @Giga-Byte If you feel that there are good peripherals, then study them ***very carefully*** and work out a way to use them. Again, grab up the worst case scenario you can imagine (often, the highest frequency and when you are moving smoothly between varying duty cycles within it) and on paper work out exactly what you can do, how much variability in the timing of it you are forced to deal with, and ask yourself if that's good enough. Also, can you make changes in the peripheral in such a way that the output "appears" the way you want it to appear as changes are made - glitch free for example?

Comment: Ok. Thank you @evildemonic and jonk for showing me the way.

Comment: @Giga-Byte Can you accept "oddball" glitches as you scroll around with your knobs? Etc. You really, really need to sit down and use ***paper***. No computer. No simulations. No libraries. No anything. Just you and your brain and the datasheet and your knowledge of instructions and peripherals. If you cannot work it out on paper, then you'll never get it right in code. You need to fully understand every single detail before you write any code, unless that code is to help you answer a question you have that isn't answered in the datasheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111936/discussion-between-giga-byte-and-jonk).